# Do all Backbone methods need to be bound to this?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In every method, that I use `this` and want it to point to the object, do I need to use `_.bindAll()`.  If not, in what cases do I need to use `bindAll()`?

```
var AccountView = Backbone.View.extend({
    Name:                 'AccountView',
    P: {
        pictures:         $A.Reg.get('path_pictures'),
        images:           $A.Reg.get('path_images')
    },
    E: {
        hold_name:        '#hold_name',
        hold_pic_small:   '#hold_pic_small',
        hold_pic_large:   '#hold_pic_large'
    },
    initialize: function () {
        $A.morph(this.E, $A.el);
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        if (_.isObject(this.model)) {
            this.obj = this.model;
        } else {
            this.obj = this.model.toJSON();
        }
        this.render();
    },
    render:  function () {
        var time = new Date().getTime();
        this.E.hold_name.innerHTML = this.obj.name;
        $A.el('#p' + this.obj.privacy).checked = true;
        if (this.obj.picture === 0) {
            this.E.hold_pic_small.src = this.P.images + 'generic_small.jpg' + '?_time=' + time;
            this.E.hold_pic_large.src = this.P.images + 'generic_large.jpg' + '?_time=' + time;
        } else {
            this.E.hold_pic_small.src = this.P.pictures + this.obj.h_file + '-1.jpg' + '?_time=' + time;
            this.E.hold_pic_large.src = this.P.pictures + this.obj.h_file + '-2.jpg' + '?_time=' + time;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll clearly explains when to use bindAll

Comment: `this` depends on how a function is called so the using `_.bindAll` depends on how the functions are going to be called. `listenTo` will use the right `this`, a view's `events` will use the right `this`, and most other things let you manually specify the desired `this` so `_.bindAll` is rarely needed at all these days.

Comment: From my question - `in what cases do I need to use bindAll()` - if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cases where you need to bind the method to the Backbone class:

- AJAX callback
- Model success callback
- DOM events listeners
- Global events listeners

Cases where you don't need to bind:

- methods invoked internally in the class in this way 'this.someMethod();' because you are already on this.
- event listeners in the event hash of the Backbone class. (delegateEvents automatically bind them to the class).

For example, in your case, you don't need to bind render, as it is called as this.render and you do not have any other listener that would cause render to lost the scope.